# random sudden logout ubuntu 17.10 lenovo yoga 910

Tags: gnome, 17.10, logout

Every once in a while I get a sudden logout.  When it goes to log back in, the login screen is sideways.  Running clean GNOME on wayland.  no pattern as to when it will log me out.

Comment: I you sure you are forced to log out cleanly, or could it be that your Gnome session crashed?

Comment: really I'm not sure, Its been years since i had linux on a computer, what log should i be looking at?

Comment: No clue.  But visually, if you logout normally you will see how it looks like.  Compare that to when you are forced, and maybe it will look different.  I cannot help you more than that; you will have to search the web to figure out what is happening.